# Checking preconditions the proper way

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I have a class with around 1300 lines and it has many CRUD-like methods that need parameters to be checked, for some of them it's more than just a few rules.

For clarity purposes, I am going to use generic names for my class and methods.

I finished implementing all the preconditions check recently, and although I have been doing it the cassical way with `if` block at the beginning of the methods and similar procedures, I ended up having kind of repeated chunks (which I tried extracting into private methods but that didn't help completely) and a class that is alright but being tidy and clear as I am I really want to restructure it.

So, this is a very succint version of my class, so you get the idea of how it looks like:

```
public class Event {
    public void setAttribute1(List<Attribute1> attribute1) {
        if (attribute1 == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Attribute1 cannot be null");

        if (attribute1.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Attribute1 cannot be empty");

        // check for repeated elements

        // check for more things

        this.attribute1 = attribute1;
    }

    public void addAttribute1(Attribute1 attr) {
        // null check

        // check not existing

        // check for more things

        attribute1.add(attr);
    }

    public void removeAttribute1(Attribute1 attr) {
        // null check

        // check not existing

        attribute1.remove(attr);
    }

    public void setMyMap(Map<K, V> myMap) {
        // null check

        // keys check

        // values check

        // more and more

        this.myMap = myMap;
    }

    // a long etc...
}
```

I end up with huge, occasionally partially repeated chunks of precondition checks. This is untidy and confusing. Especially when I have many similar methods for the same attribute, where I have the same checks, except that they are not the same. In case the example above doesn't help understand what I mean, this would be a case that repeats a lot in my class:

```
public class Event {
    private List<K> kDomain;
    private List<V> vDomain;
    private int kConfig;

    public void setMap(Map<K, Set<V>> map) {
        // null check

        // all k in K should be in kDomain

        // the length of the map should match an arithmetical operation based on the value of kConfig
        // (and similar checks)

        // a null Set<V> associated to a K should be illegal

        // for each k, each v in V should be in vDomain
    }

    public void addVtoK(K k, V v) {
        // null check k and v

        // k must be in kDomain

        // v must be in vDomain

        // if k has already a set of Vs, v must not be in that set already (already existing object check)
    }

    public void addVsToK(K k, Set<V> vs) {
        // null check k and vs

        // k must be in kDomain

        // all v in vs should be in vDomain

        // no v in vs can already be associated to k
    }
}
```

As you can see I have long checks that look very similar, but they are not the same.

I am trying to look for best ways to restructure my whole class which I am pretty sure I am going to end up rewriting.

I have looked into [Guava Preconditions](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) and it looks neats, but although it'd be an enhancement to the code, there are certain preconditions to be checked that are a tiny bit more complex to process and need deeper design thinking.

What would be the a proper approach? Or I am overthinking my issue?

Comment: You're already doing the preconditions the best possible way, by having them in each individual method.  DRY doesn't apply to preconditions, and adding a library would only further complicate things.  If all of that duplication bothers you, look elsewhere for better design decisions, possibly fewer methods that do more (i.e. business operations instead of CRUD methods).

Comment: business operations instead of CRUD methods meaning?

Comment: `BuildWidget(parts)`, or `TransferMoney(sourceAccount, targetAccount)`

Comment: I don't think that would be the case where my system would fit in though. I just want those CRUD-like methods to provide programmers short-hand ways of configuring an event or similar classes in my project (with configuring I mean initializing and modifying some of its members)

Comment: Then I think the way you're doing it is already ideal.

Comment: A number of the checks you're doing are the kind of checks that the compiler would happily do at compile time (e.g. k is member of kDomain, vs is in vDomain) if you could specify more type information at compile time.  Can you share with us what `K` and `V` are?  Of particular interest is whether there is one main (perhaps long-lived) data structure with `K` and `V` being constant or there are lots of little data structures with different `K` and `V`.

Comment: It's hard to say from this sample, but one possibility to consider is breaking responsibility into two classes. Suppose that Foo has relatively weak checks up until you call some kind of "apply" or "finalize" method, which would do a pass of stricter-checks before creating/modifying your Bar, which would be the object that *has* to be in a legal state at all times.

Comment: "The a proper approach" is probably to try out something like "Guava Preconditions" (or write your own, similar component, if that suits your needs better), and see how far you can get with this.

Comment: @ErikEidt I did not understand your first question. And about the last: the actual class models a sport events, and then I also have a `Tournament` class which contains many events. The main functionality of the library is to calculate all possibles schedules for the tournament. So you just set up the configuration for each event, build the necessary object and launch the solving process.

Comment: Some of the preconditions remind me of type checking done at runtime.  If you could use more differentiated types at compile time, then perhaps you can used the language's type system and compile time checks and thus remove some of the runtime checks.

Comment: "I have a class with around 1300 lines"... you need to split that up into smaller parts. rarely should a programmer exceed 1000 lines.

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar many of the methods are "utility" methods with "optional" parameters, etc... so it's not 1300 lines of pure business logic.

Answer (score 4):

Whilst it's admirable to check your preconditions, I wonder:

1. is your class usage such that you'll need to check all these ? e.g. I will check preconditions for a set of components that are exposed for more general usage, but for more limited usage in which I know how the component will be used, I won't perform so many checks. The counter argument to this is that if you extract a component for more widespread use (e.g. in a library) then you'll have to apply more preconditions, but it's a pragmatic approach
2. Are all of these checks really necessary ? e.g. if I specify an empty Set of elements to be added, do I really care that nothing will get added ? I don't want my client code to be littered with empty Set checks when adding to this entity. Just let the entity deal with it (i.e. do nothing)

If, despite the above, you have masses of repeated code for your preconditions, maybe check out [Java's dynamic proxies](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076233/java-se/explore-the-dynamic-proxy-api.html). These allow you to write a wrapper method that will wrap all method invocations on your object. You can then check if the method you're calling is a `setXYZ()`, and if you're adding a set of attributes, or just one, and you can invoke the preconditions generically before delegating further to your real implementation.

Comment: Regarding point 1, my project is a library so... I need to check those preconditions with rigour. Regarding point 2, some empty checks are necessary and some are not. My actual preconditions actually seldom check empty collections.

Comment: Instead of using Java Proxies directly, you could use an AOP library such aspectj / Spring-AOP which would allow you to define these add-on validation rules in a more convenient manner.

Comment: AOP is certainly another approach that would work here, yes

Answer (score 1):

It is the responsibility of the method to validate its own inputs. It should do so thoroughly and rigorously, regardless of whether or not you are building a library. There's rarely (imo) a good reason to skip on proper input validation. Handling edge cases as part of the natural set of inputs if they return a meaningful result is acceptable (e.g. letting empty sets iterate 0 times over a loop).

Validating parameters for each method independently can involve some repetition if similar validation happens in different methods. You can be OK with that repetition:

DRY is over-rated - it almost always creates tighter coupling between processes, and in this context could also effectively introduce coupling, indirectly between your (assumedly) otherwise independent methods. If you were to refactor this in a way that validates the parameters centrally, then you'll make multiple methods dependent on validator method(s). I would not always recommend that approach, it can quickly explode in combinatorial complexity, especially if then later you find that your validator methods depend on other methods and/or later call many other methods... etc. Then you have a trivial piece of code (the validator) has become embedded deep within the call hierarchy and can become very hard to refactor to a less spaghetti-like architecture.

The parts that can be OK to DRY in this context are single responsibility, re-used, non-trivial (but not huge) pieces of logic that are likely to remain fairly simple "leaf" methods of the call tree over time. Do not however, apply DRY to simple checks e.g. checking for not null. It's a balance between code simplicity and maintainability on the one hand and not creating too much tight coupling that could entrench inflexibility in future.

Comment: but if I don't DRY it up and preconditions ever change, I would need to modify every single one of them (in the methods they're used) and risking missing some

Comment: I've added a paragraph to my answer to address your comment